# Could Flutter's ReorderableListView drag item out of line?

Tags: flutter

I'm using Flutter's ReorderableListView to display some images picked from photo library.
After I picked some images, I want drag one image onto a trash bin icon to delete it from selection. Assume the trash bin icon is at the bottom of screen. Since we can't drag item out of Listview's area,
How could I do it? Or if there is any other plugin could do this job?